# Assign values to particular array for particular condition in for loop python

Tags: python, arrays

I have two arrays, for every item in list `table`, I want to write data to corresponding item in list `drive`, inside a `for loop` in python

```
drive1 =[]

drive2 =[]

drive4 =[]

tables = ['values_1', 'values_2', 'values_4']

drive = [ drive1, drive2, drive4]

for item in tables and drive:

    tab = db[item]
```

Comment: what type are the elements of `drive`

Comment: its an array of array

Comment: what is "corresponding item" ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am little confused by what you're asking, but I think this answers it...

If you just want to append to a corresponding list, try:

```
for item, drive_item in zip(tables, drive):
    drive_item.append(item)
```

Because lists are mutable, you don't need to set the return equal to anything.